# How to make sure threaded task is run

Tags: c#, threadpool

Not really language specific, but I have this in C#:

```
public static void StartJob() {
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(s => {
        if (Monitor.TryEnter(_lock)) {
            ProcessRows();
            Monitor.Exit(_lock);
        }
    }
);
```

`ProcessRows()` processes and removes rows in a database until all rows are removed. At program launch and whenever a row is added to the database elsewhere in the program, `StartJob` is called, to ensure all rows are processed without blocking the program. Now if a row is added at exactly the same time as `StartJob` is about to release the lock, it will not be processed.

How do I ensure that all rows are processed? I prefer not to have `ProcessRows()` run unless rows are added.

Comment: You'd need the thing that adds rows to the database to signal your program to say that it can start processing.  You can use some global Mutex for that.

Comment: "Now if a row is added at exactly the same time as StartJob is about to release the lock, it will not be processed." - Are you sure? Has this happened to you?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: it's pretty unlikely, but there is a theoretical race condition there because `ProcessRows` completes before the lock is released; a second thread could fail the `.TryEnter` even though `ProcessRows` isn't running.

Comment: @DanPuzey: You are correct. I wasn't reading properly and thought that the other threads would block until the lock is released (as in Monitor.Enter).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't lock around the method; lock within the method using a flag that says whether you're running or not.

One implementation might look like the code below - in this case I've moved all the logic into `ProcessRows` and made the method return immediately if it's already running.

```
public static bool _isRunning = false;

public static void StartJob() 
{ 
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(s => { ProcessRows(); })
} 

public static void ProcessRows()
{
    Monitor.Enter(_lock);
    if (_isRunning) 
    {
        Monitor.Exit(_lock);
        return;
    }

    _isRunning = true;

    while (rowsToProcess)
    {
        Monitor.Exit(_lock);;

        // ... do your stuff

        Monitor.Enter(_lock);
    }

    _isRunning = false;
    Monitor.Exit(_lock);
}
```

With this structure, it's impossible for the `while` loop to complete without setting `_isRunning = false` - if this weren't the case, there would be a race condition if the loop completed just as another instance of the method started.  Equally, when the method is called, it will always enter the loop and set `_isRunning = true` before another instance gets a chance to execute.